# How can I do this double border with offset in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

I need to be able to create this double border with CSS only.
[image]

A simple double border is sure easy, but i need an offset for the second.
Does anyone know how to do it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `box-shadow` you can do something like this.

One shadow will be a solid color, we then use a second to cover the inside.

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-shadow: 
  8px 8px 0px 1px white
  , 8px 8px 0px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Damn, thank you, I played for 15 minutes with box-shadow, but didn't know you could double it !